# DataGridView - How does one hook into the event associated with a cell change?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView with C#.NET.  When a user is editing a column, I need another column in the same grid to change with every keystroke/change.  How/where do I insert my own code for this type of event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible without a bit of work.  By default the `DataGridView` class does not provide a `CellChanging` style event.  Instead it provides book ended events in the form of `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit`.

Part of the reason is likely due to the varying ways in which a cell can be editted.  Having a `CellChanging` would make sense for a text style cell but wouldn't make as much sense for say a `Button` style cell.

You could easily implement a solution though which propagated the value once it was completely entered via the above said events.

The only way I can see to implement it for every keystroke would be to

1. Handle the above events
2. Figure out what the runtime type of `DataGridView.EditingControl` is and find a way to hook into every single change for every type of cell
3. Propagate the changes on every edit

Even then I think you still may run into issues because I'm not sure if `DataGridView` is designed to have cell values changed while a different one is being actively edited.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can think of that nothing occurs when I do use the following code?

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1[3, e.RowIndex].Value = "test";
            dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "another test";
        }

Essentially, neither 0,0 nor 0,X are affected when I click a cell, edit the text, and press enter.